# Does Steam work on Windows 8?

Tags: steam, windows-8

I am considering installing Windows 8 RTM on my gaming PC. Has anyone tried installing and using Steam on Windows 8?

Is Windows 8 supported by Valve/Steam in the first place? Is there any known issues?

Comment: I would wait 60 days until Windows 8 is release released.

Comment: @Ramhound The RTM (or "Release To Manufacturing" version) is the *final version* of Windows 8, not a beta or a preview. It is the same software that will be released to the public.

Comment: While Steam itself is working, I cannot to get L.A. Noire to run on Windows 8 RTM. Someone made their own patch to get it working with the new OS and [shared it](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2599851&page=5), but I'm not comfortable running it against my machine.

Comment: @Brant - Its still not a supported operating system by Valve.

Comment: +1 from me, great question! (Though technically, isn't this "too localized"?)

Comment: No issues with Steam or any other game I have played via Steam.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://store.steampowered.com/about/ says that right now Windows 8 is not *officially* supported. If something goes wrong, you're on your own.

That said, I've been using Steam under Windows 8 for the last few months. There are no issues I'm aware of and pretty much everything I tried worked fine. YMMV

Answer (score 6):

Nearly all games I've tried on Windows 8 have worked through Steam. With the exception of Crysis 2 and Just Cause 2 as far as I remember. These should hopefully be fixed in due course anyway.

Comment: Have you tried Shogun 2? It doesn't start for me and a lot of other players... I tried it a month ago, didn't looks for updates recently though

Answer (score 0):

Almost none of my games work, none of my steam games work. The only game that I have on windows 8 that kinda works is medal of honor, and it autokicks me from every multiplayer server for no reason. (I tried updating punkbuster, etc)

Comment: Can you list which games you've tried that don't work?

Comment: I've been playing Supreme Commander 2 without any problems. But Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War - Chaos Rising does not work. That's the only two games I've tried so far.